# jQuery undefined after $(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, undefined

I can't seem to pinpoint why this is failing - any ideas? -> See within .aspx

**custom.master** references / and script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/css/custom.css" />
<script src="/admin/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/js/jquery-1.10.2-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); <-- This here is the culprit
```

**Within rPage.aspx** (MasterPageFile="~/admin/custom.master")

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); //**Without this line the next line fails**
        $("#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

**Error:**

*from console*: `TypeError: $ is not a function rPage:380:13`

*from debugger firefox dev edition*:

```
378 $(function () {
379        //var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
380        $("#ContentPlaceHolder_txtStartDate").datepicker();
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan One of them is jQuery ui

Comment: @mkaatman I need better glasses XD

Comment: In your first example, it works because you've assigned jQuery to a local variable, i.e., not a global. So your second example would need the same thing unless you redefined `$` to be jQuery in the global scope.

Comment: @MikeC there is only 1 example - one is from the debugger from failing. as reference.

Comment: Presumably `$` is being overwritten at some point between line 378 being executed and the DOM Ready event triggering the function that includes line 380. You haven't provided enough code to tell where.

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log($)`? That ought to give you an idea of what's replacing jQuery.

Comment: Seeing as `$(function() {` works, and jQ passes a reference to itself as the first argument to the callback, you can write `$(function($) {` or `jQuery(function($) {`, which is the more common approach when you have conflicts. It's likely that the `$` name in your `$(function() {` isn't the jQ object to begin with (prototype uses `$`, too I think)

Comment: @MikeC - `console.log($)` Returns undefined.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem So - jQuery and $ at line 377 return  `function b()` - using `$(function ($)` works as well as `jQuery(function ($)` is this a standard? Is not still weird for `$(function ()` not to work?

Comment: @Quentin Masterpage references >  head placeholder, which does actually reference `<link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` from the .aspx page - but no script. > then my script from above. - Nothing else is called to my knowledge.

Comment: @All - Ok so I did leave out some script from the master page -.- edited the above. I take it that `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` is self disposing or something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the (currently) posted example, I see no reason for the `NoConflict` call. I am assuming it is because maybe the other library isn't (yet) shown in your sample code.

That said...

Try moving your `NoConflict` declaration outside of your Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) & right BEFORE you bring-in your other library..

**Like so...**

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.

$(function () {
     // Do awesome stuff here...
})();
</script>
```

**I also suggest...**

Aliasing jQuery into your IIFE's like so...

```
<script>
    $(function ($) {
         // Do awesome stuff here...
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: One quick question - what with the extra })`()`; before ending the script?

Comment: See my update.  You can alias arguments passed into your IIFE (if you like)  - Cheers!